Has anyone set up a Bitbucket pipeline to generate an automatic build for a React Native app?
I’m trying to set up a Bitbucket pipeline for a React Native app, but I’m encountering an issue during the setup of the Java environment for building the Android APK. The pipeline fails when attempting to install OpenJDK-17 with the following error:
E: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/stretch/updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 146.75.30.132 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 146.75.30.132 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch-updates/

It seems like the repositories used by the default Debian image are outdated or unavailable. I'm running the pipeline with the node:12 image.
Has anyone encountered this issue, or does anyone have suggestions for fixing the package repository URLs or using a different base image for the Bitbucket pipeline? Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!
I was expecting the pipeline to successfully install the necessary dependencies, set up the Java environment, and build the Android APK without errors. Specifically, I hoped that the OpenJDK-17 installation would succeed, allowing the build step to proceed without issues.

Can you provide your bitbucket-pipelines.yml file ? It could be helpful to help you.
